How to partition by patient and labresulttype and moment, to select the result closest to begin of momentcode and pivot to wide format?
In Rstudio I've got a dataset with labresult similar to like below. It has the values Crea, Gluc and Hb and each patient has a participation start date.
Note: the real dataset is larger, with more patients and more labresults.
I've added a column with days since, and I want to add a column MomentCode to mark the records as closest to baseline, month3 and month12, with a tolerance of one week (7 days).
After that I want to limit to only the single labresults closest (but not before) the baseline, 3 months, 12 months etc.
So in the end, the result format should be something like this:



PatientID
ParticipationDate
BASELINE_Crea
BASELINE_Gluc
BASELINE_Hb
MONTH3_Crea
MONTH3_Gluc
MONTH3_Hb
MONTH12_Crea
MONTH12_Gluc
MONTH12_Hb




PAT_001
05-01-2023
5.0
5.0
etc
etc







PAT_220
12-03-2023
5.0
5.0










I'm doing everything step-by-step but maybe there's a better way?
See code below
df <- read.table(text = "
PatientID,ParticipationDate,LabResultDate,LabType,LabValue,Verified
PAT_001,05-01-2023,05-01-2023,Crea,5.0,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,07-01-2023,Gluc,4.2,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,09-01-2023,Hb,4.2,No
PAT_220,12-03-2023,03-03-2023,Hb,5.2,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,15-03-2023,Hb,5.3,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,16-03-2023,Gluc,4.4,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,03-04-2023,Gluc,4.6,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,06-04-2023,Crea,5.4,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,07-04-2023,Crea,5.0,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,08-04-2023,Hb,5.1,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,11-06-2023,Gluc,5.3,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,12-06-2023,Crea,4.8,No
PAT_220,12-03-2023,14-06-2023,Hb,4.6,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,28-06-2023,Crea,3.9,No
PAT_220,12-03-2023,23-07-2023,Hb,5.1,No
PAT_001,05-01-2023,27-07-2023,Gluc,4.3,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,29-07-2023,Crea,5.1,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,25-08-2023,Gluc,4.9,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,27-08-2023,Crea,4.3,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,14-09-2023,Crea,5.5,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,17-09-2023,Hb,5.5,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,09-11-2023,Hb,5.4,No
PAT_001,05-01-2023,13-11-2023,Gluc,4.2,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,17-11-2023,Hb,5.2,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,29-12-2023,Crea,5.4,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,31-12-2023,Crea,4.4,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,03-01-2024,Gluc,4.2,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,09-01-2024,Gluc,5.4,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,09-01-2024,Hb,4.0,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,13-01-2024,Crea,4.7,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,07-03-2024,Hb,4.2,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,14-03-2024,Gluc,4.4,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,15-03-2024,Crea,5.0,No
PAT_220,12-03-2023,17-03-2024,Hb,3.9,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,23-05-2024,Crea,4.4,Yes
PAT_001,05-01-2023,23-06-2024,Gluc,4.8,No
PAT_220,12-03-2023,04-08-2024,Hb,4.3,Yes
PAT_220,12-03-2023,24-08-2024,Gluc,4.5,Yes
", header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = "")

# days since participation
df$DaysSince <- as.numeric(difftime(df$ParticipationDate, df$LabResultDate, units = "days"))

# mark as moment (one week tolerance) how to??
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(MomentCode = case_when(
           DaysSince>=0   && DaysSince<7     ~ "Baseline",
           DaysSince>=90  && DaysSince<90+7  ~ "Month3",
           DaysSince>=365 && DaysSince<365+7 ~ "Month12"
         )
  )

# patition by patient and code and moment to get only values closest to each moment code, how??

# pivot to wide format, how??


You could abs(df$DaysSince to address @thothal point 2 below, points 3 & 4 and their handling may or may not obscure actual actions that may or may not be desirable if this were in say a clinical trial like setting where one might like to know.

A couple of comments regarding your example data:

You calculate the difference between lab result and participation which should be the other way round.
There are negative DaysSince (LabResultDate before ParticipationDate which does not make sense)
There are differences between particpation and lab measurement which do not fall in either of your defined categories (less than 90 days but more than 7 days)
There are multiple measurements for a given time frame lab type combination.

Having said that, I made the following assumptions:

We define 2 cutoffs: 7 days & 97 days. Any difference <= 7 days will fall into the baseline, differences > 7 days and <= 97 days fall into the 3 month slot and differnces > 97 days fall into the 12 month slot (however, it is rather easy to extend the persiods simply by adding more cutoofs / labels to cut the rest of the code would remain the same in this case)
If there is more than one measurement per combination we take the mean of those measurements:

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df2 <- df %>%
  as_tibble() %>% ## format as tibble for nicer printing
  mutate(## format date columns as date
         across(ends_with("Date"), dmy), 
         ## calculate differences in days
         DaysSince = as.numeric(difftime(LabResultDate, ParticipationDate, unit = "days")), 
         ## split day differences into buckets with cutoffs 7 and 97 days
         MomentCode = cut(DaysSince, c(-Inf, 7, 97, Inf), c("Baseline", "Month3", "Month12")),
         ## create new column comnbining LabType and MomentCode
         Measurement = paste(LabType, MomentCode, sep = "_")
  )

df2 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Measurement, 
              values_from = LabValue, 
              id_cols = PatientID:ParticipationDate, 
              ## take mean for duplicated measurements
              values_fn = mean)

# # A tibble: 2 × 11
#   PatientID ParticipationDate Crea_Baseline Gluc_Baseline Hb_Baseline Gluc_Month3 Crea_Month3 Hb_Month3
#   <chr>     <date>                    <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 PAT_001   2023-01-05                    5           4.2        4.2          4.6         5.2       5.1
# 2 PAT_220   2023-03-12                   NA           4.4        5.25         5.3         4.8       4.6
# # ℹ 3 more variables: Crea_Month12 <dbl>, Hb_Month12 <dbl>, Gluc_Month12 <dbl>



For anyone interested I took the answer by thothal but added a case_when and filter to only select labvalues in brackets with a window of -7/+7 days, and then only select the first one.
This excludes a lot of values, but this was a requirement of the researcher. For example a lab value 250 days after participation should not be counted as part of the 3 month or 1 year measurement.
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    ## calculate differences in days
    DaysSince = as.numeric(difftime(LabResultDate, ParticipationDate, unit = "days")), 
    ## split day differences into buckets
    MomentCode = case_when(
      DaysSince >=    -7 & DaysSince <     7 ~ "BASE",
      DaysSince >=  90-7 & DaysSince <  90+7 ~ "M03",
      DaysSince >= 365-7 & DaysSince < 365+7 ~ "M12",
      DaysSince >= 730-7 & DaysSince < 730+7 ~ "M24",
      TRUE ~ NA # default case
    ),
    ## create new column combining LabType and MomentCode
    Measurement = ifelse(is.na(MomentCode), NA, paste(MomentCode, LabType, sep = "_"))
  )

# Create new "order" column based on sorted VisitDate
df <- df %>%
  arrange(PatientID, ParticipationDate, Measurement) %>%
  group_by(PatientID, Measurement) %>%
  mutate(order = ifelse(is.na(MomentCode), NA, row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(order == 1) %>% # select only first (closest to measuremoment)
  select(-MomentCode) # remove helper column

# Labvalues pivot to wider/columns
library(tidyr)
pivot_df <- df  %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Measurement,
              values_from = LabValue, 
              id_cols = c(PatientID, ParticipationDate), 
              # take mean, incase any duplicated measurements
              values_fn = mean)

# View the result
print(pivot_df)

And the example result is this. Btw the real data has much much more records, so also less NAs or missing pivot-columns.
  PatientID ParticipationDate BASE_Crea M24_Gluc M03_Crea
  <chr>     <chr>                 <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 PAT_001   05-01-2023                5      4.2     NA  
2 PAT_220   12-03-2023               NA      4.4      4.8

